# Confusing uage of present perfect infinitive where past perfect should be used

Tags: grammar, past-perfect, perfect-infinitive

In one of the renowned grammar books I've come across an example of confusing usage of the perfect infinitive, where in my opinion past perfect should be used instead:

***He is thought to have been deeply depressed at the time, but recovered later.***

The above sentence is placed in the past, so why there is perfect infinitive? I'd say the following sentence is more logical:

***He is thought to had been deeply depressed at that time, but recovered later.***

Can anybody explain it to me, please?

Comment: The verb "have" in your first example is not the present tense form. It is complement of "thought" and hence is the plain (infinitival) form "have".

Comment: There is no past perfect infinitive in English - *to had been* cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a conjugated form after "to". "Had" has to have a subject in the third person (he, she, it, this man, a person, etc.); the subject of "is" is "he"; then there is no subject for "had"; that is because "had" is wrong here, you must have the bare infinitive: "have".

You also have to keep in mind the usual construction in the passive for "think".

- **to be thought to be** sth/sb ([OALD, 1](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/think_1?q=think))

Is only conjugated the first occurrence of "to be". When you state a fact about  events, situations, people and so on and that this fact is still valid in the present , the plain infinitive is used.

- They are thought to be taking this seriously.

If the fact is a thing of the past, then you use the perfect infinitive.

- They are all thought to have been killed in the last war but nothing is less sure.

That is the case of your sentence: he **was** depressed in the past (at least some people think he was); it is a thing of the past.